# Socket.io emits data with delay when called inside on listener of an EventEmitter

Tags: node.js, sockets, events, websocket, socket.io

I have a smartcard reader. It sends the read data to the process through an event emitter called `emitter` (which extends from Nodejs' native `events` module). And I am emitting the received String data to the frontend using Socket.io:

```
emitter.on('cardReceived', (studentRfid) => {
    socket.emit('attended', studentRfid);
    console.log('Attended!');
});
```

The problem is: when the card is read, the log `Attended!` is immediately printed on the screen. But the data comes to the frontend with a delay (about 5 seconds).

Initially, I thought the problem was with the network/socket.

However, I have tried to emit some data as fast as in intervals of 10ms to the frontend (outside of the 'on' listener), surprisingly it did not cause any delays. The data transfer was perfectly in sync:

```
setInterval(() => { 
    socket.emit('message', 'some message'); 
}, 10 );
```

So the problem is not with Socket.io or network (it is super fast as you can see above).

What may cause these long delays?